# Swift / How to parse the correct element from a web blog with NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to download specific information from a web blog with the following code:

```
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

        if elementName == "item" {
            currentEvent = EventPosts()
            return
        }

        if elementName == "eventDate" {
            parsedElement = "eventDates"
        }    
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

        let str = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

        if parsedElement == "eventDates" && str != "" {
            if currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty {           
                currentEvent.eventDates = str
                    print(currentEvent.eventDates)
        }
    }
```

The issue is, that the parser downloads 1 element from "*eventDates*" from the [**web blog feed**](http://gecko.davidseek.com/feed/) and 3 elements of the "*title*" and I don't get why...

Any idea how to fix this issue? Help is very appreciated.

Edit: the ouput is

```
04.03.16 (thats an element of eventDate)
DJanes Delight 17.03.16 (thats an element of title)
Geiles Leben ab 04.03.16 (thats an element of title)
Wildstyle jeden Samstag (thats an element of title)
```

but it should be:

```
04.03.16
03.03.16
02.03.16
01.03.16
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. What are you expecting the output to be (i.e list of EventPosts)? And what is the actual output you are receiving?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I thought I've already made this clear. the output is 1 time the correct element and 3 times an incorrect one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you never reset the parsedElement variable once it is used which will cause the outer if statement in `func parser` to always be true once it has been set

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    if elementName == "item" {
        currentEvent = EventPosts()
        return
    }

    if elementName == "eventDate" {
        parsedElement = "eventDates"
    }    
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    let str = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

    if parsedElement == "eventDates" && str != "" {
        if currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty {           
            currentEvent.eventDates = str
            parsedElement = ""
                print(currentEvent.eventDates)
    }
}
```

While this solution might work in the most basic case you might want to read up on XML SAX parsing. There are a lot of explanations for Java out there but it is the same principle.